# Concat @Query value from function parameter in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

can we append the value of Query via QUERY from the string?
if not, is there any other alternative?

**NOTE: NEED TO RETURN DATA IN PAGE**

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select entity from table entity where 
1=1" + query + "AND date =:date")

Page getSearchedTable(String query, @Param("date") LocalDate businessDate, Pageable pageable);

Comment: are you trying to pass query string dynamically, Right?

Comment: Yes sir, Trying to concat the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query to get pageable data. Keep few points in mind

1. You must give space between equal sign and parameter like (data = :date)
2. No need to give nativeQuery = true, you can use entity fields
3. You can not use "query" as your variable in native query in spring boot. You must pass as a parameter from service.
4. Just pass your query parameter in required query like select or as per your req. with below example.

---

```
@Query(value = "select entity from table entity where  1=1 AND date = :date AND query = :query")
Page<YourTableEntity> getSearchedTable(@Param("query") String query, @Param("businessDate") LocalDate businessDate, Pageable pageable);
```

However, if you have to mandatory use nativeQuery, then you can choose any of the following queries.

---

**1. First option**

```
 @Query(
      value = "select entity from table entity where  1=1 AND date = :date AND query = :query ORDER BY id", 
      countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM table", 
      nativeQuery = true)
      Page<YourTableEntity> getSearchedTable(@Param("query") String query, @Param("businessDate") LocalDate businessDate, Pageable pageable);
```

---

**2. Second option**

```
@Query(value = "select entity from table entity where  1=1 AND date = :date AND query = :query ORDER BY id \n-- #pageable\n", 
      countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM table",
      nativeQuery = true)
      Page<YourTableEntity> getSearchedTable(@Param("query") String query, 
      @Param("businessDate") LocalDate businessDate, Pageable pageable);
```